# Remote Desktop to a device on my network connected to a VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I have a work laptop that can connect to my work's network using Juniper Network Connect. The laptop is connected to my network via ethernet cable.

What I want to do is to use the VPN on my laptop and log in to my work network, then remote desktop into the laptop from my personal computer to do work on it. I can remote into the laptop under any other circumstances - I'm using win7 pro and remote desktop is enabled. However, once I establish VPN connection, remote desktop is unable to find my laptop. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same issue with Juniper VPN access on my work laptop; I have found the simplest of solutions to connect via RDP to my work Laptop whilst having the work Laptop connected via VPN is to plug in said work laptop with two connections into your local network; I have it connected over WIFI and connected with the LAN port.

That way your work VPN will bind to your WIFI adapter, and you can continue to connect to the laptop via the LAN adapter. No funny messing around with settings from the work laptop that could get you in hot water.

Answer (score 0):

When you VPN into another network with a tool like the Juniper or Cisco clients, a virtual adapter is created which establishes a connection at layer 2, allowing the remote terminal to appear to be physically connected to the remote network, and as such it is no longer connected to the local lan. additionally, IP settings on that adapter and the system, like default gateway and DNS server addresses are altered to fit the remote network.

Split-Tunneling refers to operating the VPN at layer 3, such that only IP traffic destined for the remote network passes from the client into the VPN tunnel, and other IP traffic is passed to the local lan per standard routing rules.

in your client, look for the settings described here:
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB3054

For Juniper, Split tunneling needs to be allowed by the remote VPN tunnel endpoint device, but if it is not, see here for some tactics: http://www.digitalinternals.com/network/workaround-for-juniper-vpn-split-tunneling-restriction/124/

Finally, you may need to make sure that the service (RDP) is bound to the correct IP address/adapter after connecting to the VPN. you can do this in and elevated powershell with `netstat -abno | findstr 3389` or in BASH with `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 3389` and noting the IP address shown. it must be an address on your lan, or 0.0.0.0. if it is 0.0.0.0 then the default gateway exit interface and ip address must be pointed to your LAN, not to the VPNs remote network. if your service points onto the vpn, then you will have to research how to specify adapter/address bindings for the service in question.